# Simple user input validation not working

Tags: c++, input

I have a simple function that accepts either 1 or 2 and reprompts for input if neither of those two numbers are entered. Right now, if I enter any number, it stays stuck on asking for valid input. I know it's something easy, but I'm not seeing it now. What am I missing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int userChoice();

int main()
{
  userChoice();

  return 0;
}

int userChoice()
{
    int input = 0;

    cout << "Enter 1 or 2: ";
    cin >> input;

    while (input != 1 || input != 2 || cin.fail())
    {
        if (cin.fail())
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
        }

        cout << "Enter only 1 or 2: ";
        cin >> input;
    }

    return input;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional in `while` is not formed correctly. It will be always true.

You need to use something like:

```
while ( !cin || (input != 1 && input != 2) )
```

**Suggestion for change of strategy**

I think it will be better to use a recursive function:

```
int userChoice()
{
   int input = 0;
   cout << "Enter 1 or 2: ";
   cin >> input;

   // If we get a valid input, return.
   if ( cin && (input == 1 || input == 2))
   {
      return input;
   }

   // If there is any error in reading, clear the stream.
   if ( !cin )
   {
      cin.clear();
      cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
   }

   // Call function again.
   return userChoice();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `while` condition to

```
while( (input != 1 && input !=2) || cin.fail())
```

Answer (score 0):

use && not ||

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int userChoice();

int main()
{
  userChoice();

  return 0;
}

int userChoice()
{
    int input = 0;

    cout << "Enter 1 or 2: ";
    cin >> input;

    while ((input != 1) && (input != 2))
    {
        if (cin.fail())
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
        }

        cout << "Enter only 1 or 2: ";
        cin >> input;
    }

    return input;
}
```